# android change light color by music beat

Tags: android, visualize

I'm developing a bluetooth light app.

I want to change the light color by music beat. I have an array of colors, for example 10 colors. And a choice of color by music beat.

I had do this:

```
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[0]);

    Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                                          byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
            //how I can do
        }

        @Override
        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                                     int samplingRate) {
            //how I can do
        }
    };

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener,
            Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 8, true, true);
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
```

Now the question is: How can I analyze byte data to get rate(probably an int?) and pick a color.

Thank for your reply.